# Copying 1 Array of Pointer to 2nd Array of Pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, copying

I have two array of pointers and I want to copy one to other

```
Int32 *Ptr1[2];
Int32 *Ptr2[2];
Int32 a,b;

Ptr1[0]=&a;
Ptr1[1]=&b;
```

I want Ptr2 to hold Ptr1[0] and Ptr2[1];

```
Ptr2[0]=Ptr1[0];
Ptr2[0]=Ptr1[1];
```

Is there any other way, because If the array is huge, copying will be a problem

I did the following

```
Ptr2=Ptr1;
```

This copies the address of Ptr1 to Ptr2 but its elements are not copied..

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) is your friend.

Comment: Hi vanza, Is this the only option?

Comment: If you want, you could use a for loop and copy each array element one-by-one. That's a staff member. I'd go with the friend.